# Where's a good place to store SQLite databases in Java Applications?

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm developing my first CLI Application in Java and I've made the decision to go with SQLite for the database back-end.

I intend for the application to be cross-platform and need some guidance on where to actually store the database on users' computers. Obviously I can't store it in the .jar file right because if they need to update the application they'll lose their data correct? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Is the 'back end' meant to be shared between different users? Is there just one instance of the database per user, or are they more like 'workspaces'?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest location is to put it in some sub-directory of the system property "user.home". You can get it with

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

In unix-like systems, for a user called 'bill' this usually maps to ~bill.
In windows systems, it maps to something like C:\Document and Settings\bill

So, if you program is called "amazing", you look for and create a directory like

```
new File
(
   new File(System.getProperty("user.home")),
   ".amazing"
);
```